# Is It Possible To Use Embedded Resource Images For ObjectListView SubItems

Tags: vb.net, image, objectlistview

I can't seem to find any information on this, but does anyone know if it is possible to use an embedded image from my.resources within an ObjectListView SubItem?

I am currently using images stored in an ImageList control, but I find for some reason, those images get corrupted and start displaying imperfections.  I don't have the problem if I pull them from the embedded resources as I previously have with the normal listview control.

I am using the ImageGetter routine to return a key reference the ImageList, however, ultimately I would like to pull these from embedded resources.  I would like to also do this for animated GIF references as well.

If anyone knows a way, could you please assist.  Sample code would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return three different types from the ImageGetter

1. int - the int value will be used as an index into the image list
2. String - the string value will be used as a key into the image list
3. Image - the Image will be drawn directly (only in OwnerDrawn mode)

So option number 3 could be what you want. Note that you have to set `objectListView1.OwnerDraw = true`.

If that does not work, an alternative could be to load the images into the ImageList at runtime. There is an [example here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#on-the-rows-of-my-objectlistview-i-want-to-show-images-that-come-from-a-database-how-do-i-do-that).

```
this.mainColumn.ImageGetter = delegate(object row) {
    String key = this.GetImageKey(row);
    if (!this.listView.LargeImageList.Images.ContainsKey(key)) {
        Image smallImage = this.GetSmallImageFromStorage(key);
        Image largeImage = this.GetLargeImageFromStorage(key);
        this.listView.SmallImageList.Images.Add(key, smallImage);
        this.listView.LargeImageList.Images.Add(key, largeImage);
    }
    return key;
};
```

> This dynamically fetches the images if they haven’t been already fetched. You will need to write the GetImageKey(), GetSmallImageFromStorage() and GetLargeImageFromStorage() methods. Their names will probably be different, depending on exactly how you are deciding which image is shown against which model object.

Comment: Thanks Rev1, I will try option 3.  The issue with the alternative could be the same issue I'm having where the ImageList images seem to corrupt (lose clarity) after running a few times.  This is why I tend to stay away from ImageList controls these days and work with embedded resources.

Comment: True regarding the ImageList. But instead of adding the images to the list only once like in the example, you could try to always remove/add the images, essentially refreshing the contents. Apart from that, it is still curious why you have problems with the ImageList in general. But thats another question.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even realise you could just return a reference to an embedded image resource within the ImageGetter delegate.  Works a treat.  One final question though, the image that I'm returning is 16x16 pixels, the empty ImageList control is 16x16 pixels, my row height is 22 pixels and the image seems to be stetching out rather than maintaining original size.

Comment: Glad it helped, so please consider accepting this answer. Regarding the image stretching I have no idea. My Bitmaps stay at original size, regardless of the row height. Maybe you use another image format that causes this? At least I haven't found an OLV option that allows to control automatic resizing.

Comment: Will definitely accept your answer @Rev1.0 as your post gave me exactly what I needed.  Just thought I'd quiz you on the stretching first.  Will play around with a few things...  Thanks again!